# Optimal code pattern to process a lists + separator in Rust

Tags: rust

A bit of a trivial Rust bike-shedding question, but I keep seeing it implemented in sub-optimal (verbose) way, and I wonder if stdlib should help, or if there is a good pattern for it?

GOALS:

- each element processing code should only be written once
- have a simple way to write "separator" handling code without additional state (i.e. without a bool flag) if possible

The hypothetically ideal code -- is it worth requesting it from Rust stdlib or at least add it to itertools (see [issue](https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/issues/697))?

```rust
fn print_functional(items: &[&str]) {
    items.foreach_with_separator(
        |elem| {
            // some arbitrary complex item handling, not printing
            print!("{elem}");
        },
        || {
            // some arbitrary complex "separator" handling
            print!(", "),
        }
    );
}
```

Mostly I saw these two approaches. They are less than ideal due to formatting code duplication or verbose context state keeping. My goal is to do it using just stdlib, without creating any complex helper functions.

```rust
fn main() {
    let items = vec!["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    print_with_var(&items);
    print_split_last(&items);
}

fn print_with_var(items: &[&str]) {
    let mut first_printed = false;
    for elem in elems {
        if first_printed {
            print!(", ");
        } else {
            first_printed = true;
        }
        // this represents some multi-line processing,
        // but for this example I'm keeping it simple
        let formatted_value = elem.to_string();
        print!("{formatted_value}");
    }
}

fn print_split_last(items: &[&str]) {
    if let Some((last, elems)) = items.split_last() {
        for elem in elems {
            // this is sub-optimal because elem formatting is duplicated
            let formatted_value = elem.to_string();
            print!("{formatted_value}, ");
        }
        let formatted_value = last.to_string();
        print!("{formatted_value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware, [`slice::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join) does exist in stdlib. If you're asking how to re-implement it, then that's cool. But if you're just looking to get the job done, it's built-in.

Comment: @Sylivo I do not need to create a string, I need to process items (see `print_functional` above for the closest to what is needed in a generic way)

Comment: Side note: The expression is [bike _shedding_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality#Argument): "Parkinson provides the example of a fictional committee whose job was to approve the plans for a nuclear power plant spending the majority of its time on discussions about relatively minor but easy-to-grasp issues, such as what materials to use for the staff bicycle shed, while neglecting the proposed design of the plant itself, which is far more important and a far more difficult and complex task."

Answer (score 2):

One *DRY* solution is to make use of [peekable iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html):

```rust
pub fn print_comma_separated(elements: Vec<&str>)  {
    let mut it = elements.iter().peekable();
    while let Some(x) = it.next() {
        print!("{}", x); 
        if it.peek().is_some() {
            print!(", ");
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    print_comma_separated(vec!["a", "b", "c"]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gnd3ME8n7

Answer (score 2):

Another [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#) approach, avoiding the string allocation from join by using [intersperse](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

pub fn print_comma_separated(elements: &Vec<&str>)  {
    for x in Itertools::intersperse(elements.iter().map(|x| Some(x)), None) {
        if let Some(x) = x {
            print!("{x}")
        } else {
            print!(", ")
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    print_comma_separated(&vec!["a", "b", "c"]);
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e899640def3f51aa994cb7a33e1b7c0)

Rust nightly has even added [`intersperse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse) to the std itself, which will be even nicer.

Comment: I think this approach is probably the closest to what I had in mind, thanks!!!  It is still a bit hacky, and limited to clonable types only (and could in theory result in code bloat because a complex clonable type might never need .clone(), but because of this, that function will be compiled in but never used... maybe)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a boolean flag. You can use the underlying iterator and then after grabbing the first element pass the rest to a `for` loop (or `.map` it for a more functional style):

```
pub fn foo(ls: &[&str]) -> Option<()> {
    // We get an iterator over the items in a slice
    let mut iter = ls.iter();

    // Get the first item. Note that it's
    // an Option, the slice may be empty.
    // If it is this will essentially
    // return early
    let first = iter.next()?;

    // Do something special with the first element
    println!("first: {first}");

    // Loop over the rest
    for item in iter {
        println!("item: {item}");
    }

    // Return an empty option to satisfy the
    // return type
    Some(())
}   

fn main() {
    foo(&vec!["a", "b", "c"]);
}
```

You can see in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74853e759f08831625c5bfa38fa60dd4) without the explanatory comments it's quite concise.

Comment: thanks, but your code has the same issue as my `print_split_last` example -- it has duplicate "print a single element" logic - which might be fairly involved.

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan put the shared logic in its own function. Although somebody else mentioned peekables, that looks like it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid string allocation with `itertools`'s [`format()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format):

```rust
fn print_functional(items: &[&str]) {
    use itertools::Itertools;
    
    println!("{}", items.iter().format(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

People that use [Itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/index.html) or don't mind the dependency have [`itertools::join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.join.html):

```rust
use itertools::join;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", join(vec!["a", "b", "c"], ", "))
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2c4607d5b243ac448fb3aae85456e38)

Or for more customization:

```
use itertools::join;

fn main() {
    let list = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
    println!("{}", join(list.iter().map(|x| {
        format!("{x}") //whatever formatting is desired
    }), ", "))
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86019c95f18d8c75d731ed9a77a3cef8)

Comment: Chris, you missed the point about formatting. I am aware of the simple cases like this. The problem is how to do non-duplicate "per-element-processing" with "separator processing"

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your question, but join *does* accept iterators. If you need further formatting you can just `join(vec!["a", "b", "c"].iter().map(|x|format!("{x}..."))`,
where the lambda can ba arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Chris, yes, but I am NOT trying to join it - joining implies allocation and copying.  I simply need to "process" each item and each "separator" between each, and that processing could be arbitrary.

Comment: That makes sense. Then you could use [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76158442/7204912).

Answer (score 0):

Making another function is the simplest way of doing this.

```rs
fn print_split_last(items: &[&str]) {
    if let Some((last, elems)) = items.split_last() {
        for elem in elems {
            let formatted_value = elem_to_string(elem);
            print!("{formatted_value}, ");
        }
        let formatted_value = elem_to_string(last);
        print!("{formatted_value}");
    }
}

fn elem_to_string(elem: &str) -> String {
    elem.to_string()
}
```

If there's a lot of state involved, you can make it a closure and capture the state.

```rs
fn print_split_last(items: &[&str]) {
    let mut state = 0;
    let elem_to_string = |elem| elem.with_state(&mut state);
    if let Some((last, elems)) = items.split_last() {
        for elem in elems {
            let formatted_value = elem_to_string(elem);
            print!("{formatted_value}, ");
        }
        let formatted_value = elem_to_string(last);
        print!("{formatted_value}");
    }
}
```

You can even take the closure as an argument. And in order to avoid creating temporary strings, you should be converting to a type that implements `Display`.

```rs
use std::fmt::Display;

fn print_split_last<T, F, D>(items: &[T], mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T) -> D,
    D: Display,
{
    if let Some((last, elems)) = items.split_last() {
        for elem in elems {
            let formatted_value = f(elem);
            print!("{formatted_value}, ");
        }
        let formatted_value = f(last);
        print!("{formatted_value}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, no-crate way to do this:

```rust
pub fn print_comma_separated(elements: Vec<&str>)  {
    let mut it = elements.iter();
    let Some(first) = it.next() else {
        return
    }
    print!("{first}");
    for x in it {
        print!(", {x}")
    }
}
```

It's clear how one would extend this to a delimiter other than `,`.

Comment: this has the same issue as a few other examples - you duplicate the printing of an element - which might be far more complex than just calling print(). I clarified the question.

Comment: Not sure why this is important. Just put whatever work needs to be done in a function and call the function.

Comment: because this type of code pattern is very common, so i am trying to find a good way for the whole community to address this, rather than reinvent the wheel each time. See https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/issues/697